# how to get wrap text using div tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to get the "wrap text" in div tag, here is what I'm using:

```html
<div style="width:650px;height:200px;overflow-y:scroll;display: inline-block; writing-mode:lr-tb; word-wrap:break-word;white-space:normal;">                               
     <asp:Label ID="bodyLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>    
</div>
```

Can any one please suggest me how to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The above thing should work fine, you should get it with scrollbars if possible. whatz the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CSS? See [this link](http://xahlee.info/js/css_text-wrap.html).

Answer (score 0):

what about loosing the label tag , and place your text in the div directly :

```
<div ID="bodyLabel" runat="server" style="width:650px;height:200px;overflow-y:scroll;display: inline-block; writing-mode:lr-tb; word-wrap:break-word;white-space:normal;">                               

</div>
```

and the text will wrap by default in the div.

dont you think its easier ?

Comment: hai Arrabi, even i use the word-wrap:break-word, the text which is going beyond the width is getting down to nextline and the next line is moving to another line leaving the current line empty, can you please suggest me what to do?

Comment: try to add "text-align:justify" to the div style